# Update data in table setting a particular date's minimum timing activity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

Table: `activity`

```
Date         Time      task_name  type
10-02-2014   07:00     Reporting  Scheduled
10-02-2014   1200      mailing    Failed
10-02-2014   16:00     Checking   Scheduled
11-02-2014   10:00     DDDD       Done
```

I want to update a column named `type` from `Scheduled` to `Done` for a particular date where time is minimum on that date. 
Below there is the query:

```
UPDATE activity 
SET type = "Done" 
WHERE 
    type = "Scheduled" 
    AND Date = "10-02-2014" 
    AND time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM activity WHERE Date = '10-02-2014');
```

But it is throwing an error:

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'activity' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Note that dates in MySQL should utilise a DATE data type - otherwise, why bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People don't half talk some nonsense around here. Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (type) VALUES
('scheduled'),('failed'),('scheduled'),('done');

UPDATE my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id < x.id 
   SET x.type = 'done' 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----------+
| id | type      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | done      |
|  2 | failed    |
|  3 | scheduled |
|  4 | done      |
+----+-----------+
```

Just by way of example, here's some code that uses a subquery - albeit an uncorrelated one...

```
UPDATE my_table x 
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) minid FROM my_table) y 
    ON y.minid = x.id 
   SET x.type = 'done';
```

Comment: But i am not updating the minid. I want to update that the time is minimum on that date.

Comment: I'm simply demonstrating a principle. Adapting this query to your purposes is (or at least 'should be') trivial!

Answer (score 1):

Because of [documented limitation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-errors.html) of MySQL, you cannot use the same table for both the subquery FROM clause and the update target table.

You should then do something like this:

```
DECLARE @minTime time
SELECT @minTime = MIN(time) FROM activity WHERE date='10-2-2014'

UPDATE activity 
SET type='Done'
WHERE date='10-2-2014' AND type='scheduled' AND time = @minTime
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please try this:**

```
update activity 
set type='Done'
where date='10-2-2014' and type='scheduled' and time in (select MIN(time) from activity where date='10-2-2014')
```

This is working for me perfectly. **i am using sql server 2008**

Hope this helps..

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'time1' in 'field list'

Comment: @Basudev..updated the answer , according to your table , the name of tehe column is time not time1..Please check..

Comment: again same error found. i am using php myadmin the default database.ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'activity' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Basudev I think you have that error because of an unsupported instruction. Please, have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-errors.html). Indeed : "You can use a subquery for assignment within an UPDATE statement because subqueries are legal in UPDATE and DELETE statements as well as in SELECT statements. However, you cannot use the same table  for both the subquery FROM clause and the update target."